# Loop reordering across function boundaries in STL Algorithms

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-optimization

For simplicity lets assume that I have a vector of `N` matrices each of `M` rows. I am using STL `std::accumulate` to compute the sum of all the matrices. I pass a binary functor that accepts two matrices (by reference) and returns their sum (by reference). Full disclosure: I am using libstdc++ parallel mode. Inside the functor I loop over the rows individually to compute the sum.

Though each matrix is too large to fit in the cache, a row fits in very nicely. So it would be advantageous to re-order the loops so that the outer loop indexes over the `M` rows and the inner one over the `N` matrices. In addition to defining the functor inline, is there anything else I can do to encourage such a cross-function-boundary loop re-ordering. I can of course restructure the code, but I would ideally like to keep the simple structure that the use of STL algorithms afford. If there is something that is gcc specific I wouldnt mind that either.

I am not actually dealing with matrices, that was just an example, but the same problem structure applies. The main issue is that of  performance. Explaining the actual scenario would be too cumbersome, but the core problem is this: STL's accumulate entails an ordering among the nested loops that isnt very cache friendly because it tries to complete the addition of two objects before moving on to the next object. A single object is too big to be held in cache, but parts of it can be. So the execution can be sped up if one computes the 'additions' one 'part' at a time (over all objects). Hand reordering the loops leads to substantial improvement in FLOPS. But I would ideally like the compiler to do the re-ordering so that I can code at the STL level (as far as possible). So I am looking for tricks to do this.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you have performance issues? Can you show us what you have?

Comment: @wilhelmtell I added some more detail. Hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: I am upvoting all the three suggestions I received so far. I am still looking for a way to prompt the compiler to do the right thing. Because the right thing varies with cache sizes. May be the solution is to use the preprocessor for conditional compilation.

Comment: All were good answers and essentially pointed to the same thing. But I can only accept one, so I went for the one that was the most explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Matrix;
class Row;
struct SumNRow {
  int _rowidx;
//  Row _tempRow; //For return by reference left out for simplicity
  SumNRow(int iRowIdx): _rowIdx(iRowIdx) {}
  Row operator(const Matrix & iMarix1, const Matrix iMatrix2) {
    return iMarix1[_rowIdx] + iMatrix2[_rowIdx];
  }
};

template<class MatrixIterator>
void sum(const MatrixIterator & iMarixStart, const MatrixIterator & iMatrixEnd, Matrix & oMarix) {
  for (int i = 0; i < iMarixStart->rowCount(); ++i) {
    oMarix[i]=std::accumulate(iMarixStart, iMatrixEnd, SumNRow(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what wilhelmtell described.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine the compiler figuring this out unless everything was inlined and M and N were constant.  Even then, it would be a stretch.

To keep STL algorithmic style, use a foreach M over the accumulate and have the functor just sum a row.

Comment: Hi @Lou M and N can be taken to be compile time constants. This will lead to some lack of flexibility but I can live with that. I do exactly what you mention, i.e. call a STL looping construct inside `accumulate` functor. But it does not seem to reorder things. Whether one should re-order or not depends on the sizes of the matrices(objects) and the cache sizes, which I think the compiler has no way of finding out. If there is a way (template magic) to force the reordering that would be great. If I have missed your suggestion please do let me know.

Comment: @srean: You seem to misunderstand this answer. I beleive reordering is pretty clear here and my answer repeats exactly the same idea.

Comment: Lou Franco: sorry for missing your answer and repeating the same thing.

Comment: @Basilevs Yes right. I did not understand that Lou Franco was also suggesting the same fix.

Answer (score 1):

Write a new algorithm, or wrap things in a for-loop or a `std::for_each()` call. It's going to be much easier than finding ways to adapt `std::accumulate()`. I think that the only other alternative here is to introduce a new abstraction level to the library, that is beyond iterators. It's easier to just write a new algorithm or introduce an extra loop.

Comment: Its not the algorithm but the data structure that is the source of sub-optimality here, i.e. the vector of un-cacheably large objects. I could split the objects in a way that they are now several vectors, each containing a part of the object, thats a significant restructuring. The problem is that this change may or may not be the right thing to do, it depends on the cache size of the machines. Ideally I would like these complications to be handled by a recompile on the target m/c. It now seems an unrealistic goal, i.e. no simple solutions. I was hoping compiler will optimize it away.